# Looping through Login Credentials - Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dictionary

Pretty new to Python and programming in general. At the moment I am trying to use a dictionary nested within a dictionary to loop through login Credentials. My Dictionary looks like this:

```
loginCredentials = {'Company1':{'User':'UserName', 'Password':'UserPassword', 'StoreID':'StoreNum'},  
                    'Company2':{'User':'UserName', 'Password':'UserPassword', 'StoreID':'StoreNum'}}
```

I'am trying to use the values associated with Company 1 to login and follow through a certain amount of steps after those are completed then I would like to continue on with Company2 and so on.

What would the for loop look like? and how would I set a key to call when entering the login criteria per step.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> loginCredentials = {'Company1':{'User':'UserName', 'Password':'UserPassword', 'StoreID':'StoreNum'}, 'Company2':{'User':'UserName', 'Password':'UserPassword', 'StoreID':'StoreNum'}}
>>> for company, credentials in loginCredentials.iteritems():
...     store_id = credentials["StoreID"]
...     password = credentials["Password"]                                  
...     username = credentials["User"]                                          
...     # do stuff                                                             
...
```

`iteritems` turns the dictionary into a list of tuples (actually it's an iterator object) containing the key and value of the dictionary items. So what's actually happening here is that you are looping over that list and the tuples are unpacked into `company` and `credentials`.

```
>>> list(loginCredentials.iteritems())
[('Company2', {'StoreID': 'StoreNum', 'Password': 'UserPassword', 'User': 'UserName'}), ('Company1', {'StoreID': 'StoreNum', 'Password': 'UserPassword', 'User': 'UserName'})]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been reading about dictionaries etc but my lack of experience can make it a bit confusing, so I really appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> *python dictionaries: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries*

```
for company, creds in loginCredentials.iteritems()
    login(company, creds["User"], creds["Password"], creds["StoreID"])
```